# Highchart tooltips overriding each other with multiple charts on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to put 3 charts onto one page using highcharts. Each chart is a partial view with its own data and is contained withing a div with a unique ID.

It all works absolutely fine, expect tooltips. The tooltip defined on the last of the charts to be loaded overwrites the tool tips on the other 2 charts.

Can anyone explain why the tooltip is being shared between these otherwise completely separate objects?

[image]

Here is the highcharts code for each partial:

```js
$('div#' + chartName).each(function (idx, eachChartContainer) {
  if (!$(eachChartContainer).parent().is(':visible')) return;
  $(eachChartContainer).highcharts('StockChart',
  {
      chart: {
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
          renderTo: chartName[idx],
          isHighcharts: false,
          events: {
              load: function () {
                  var chart = $(eachChartContainer).highcharts();
                  if (chartInterval === '1_day') {
                      chart.series[0].update({
                          tooltip: { xDateFormat: '%a %e %b, %Y %H:%M' }
                      });
                  } else {
                      chart.series[0].update({
                          tooltip: { xDateFormat: '%a %e %b, %Y' }
                      });
                  }
              }
          },
          height: 180,
          resetZoomButton: {
              theme: {
                  fill: '#fff',
                  stroke: '#fff',
                  r: 2,
                  states: { hover: { fill: '#fff' } }
              }
          },
          spacingBottom: 0,
          spacingLeft: 0,
          zoomType: chartZoomType
      },
      rangeSelector: {
          selected: 0,
          inputEnabled: true,
          allButtonsEnabled: true,
          enabled: false
      },
      navigator: { enabled: false, adaptToUpdateData: true },
      scrollbar: { enabled: false, liveRedraw: true },
      plotOptions: {
          series: {
              dataGrouping: {
                  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                      millisecond: ['%a %e %b, %Y %H:%M:%S.%L', '%a, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L'],
                      second: ['%a %e %b, %Y %H:%M:%S', '%a, %b %e, %H:%M:%S'],
                      minute: ['%a %e %b, %Y %H:%M', '%a %e %b, %Y %H:%M'],
                      hour: ['%a %e %b, %Y %H:%M', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M'],
                      day: ['%a %e %b, %Y', '%a %e %b'],
                      week: ['%a %e %b, %Y', '%a %e %b'],
                      month: ['%B %Y', '%B'],
                      year: ['%Y', '%Y']
                  }
              },
              animation: { duration: 2000, easing: 'swing' }
          }
      },
      tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: 'p',
          xDateFormat: '%a %e %b, %Y %H:%M',
          formatter: function () {
              return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b, %Y', this.x) + "<br />" + epic + ": <b>" + this.y + "</b>";
          }
      },
      xAxis: {
          ordinal: extendGraph,
          max: endOfMarket,
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
              second: '%H:%M:%S',
              minute: '%H:%M',
              hour: '%H:%M',
              day: '%e %b',
              week: '%e %b',
              month: '%b %y',
              year: '%Y'
          },
          title: { text: '' },
          labels: {
              y: 24,
              x: 8
          }
      },
      yAxis: {
          labels: {
              align: 'right',
              formatter: function () {
                  var chart = $(eachChartContainer).highcharts();
                  if (this.value === undefined || this.value === null || this.value === 0) {
                      return '0';
                  }
                  if (chart.yAxis[0].dataMax === chart.yAxis[0].dataMin) {
                      return this.value;
                  }
                  if (chart.yAxis[0].max - chart.yAxis[0].min <= 1) {
                      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 3);
                  }
                  if (chart.yAxis[0].max >= -4 && chart.yAxis[0].max <= 0) {
                      return this.value;
                  }
                  if (chart.yAxis[0].max <= 0.2) {
                      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 3);
                  } else if (chart.yAxis[0].max > 0.2 && chart.yAxis[0].max <= 4) {
                      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2);
                  }
                  return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, null, '.', ',');
              },
              x: -8,
              y: 3,
          },
          min: 0,
          opposite: false,
          showFirstLabel: true,
          showLastLabel: true,
          tickPixelInterval: 60,
          tickPositioner: function () {
              var positions = [];
              if (this.dataMax <= 3) {
                  return null;
              }
              if (this.dataMax == this.dataMin) {
                  return null;
              }
              var tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                  increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);
              for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                  positions.push(tick);
              }
              return positions;
          },
          title: {
              text: marketCurrency
          }
      },
      series: [
          {
              threshold: null,
              fillOpacity: 0.5,
              pointInterval: 300000,
              pointStart: { pointStart: Date.parse('01/24/2017 08:00:00') },
              data: data,
              name: epic,
              type: 'area'
          }
      ]
  });
                })
```

The container divs ID is passed in the chartName variable

The epic variable is used in the div IDs to identify the charts, and should be used in the tooltip (thats the bit not working)

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Please share your HTML as well, or make a Demo so we can check it.

Comment: Please create some live working example of this issue. There're a lot of variables in your code that are not defined (`marketCurrencty`, `chartInterval`, `chartZoomType`). I tried to reproduce the problem in this fiddle by commenting out unknown variables, but everything seems to be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/c4cw2t5k/